# How to avoid freezing the UI on heavy computation

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

Trying to decrypt JSON from server with Interceptor (from [dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio)). But UI freezes during decryption.

```
class DecryptInterceptor extends Interceptor {

  @override
  Future onResponse(Response response) async {
    response.data = decrypt(response.data); //freezes here
    return super.onResponse(response);
  }

}

Object decrypt(Object object){
  // computations
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `compute` property that flutter provides to perform tasks in another isolate. It exists exactly for such tasks.

```dart
class DecryptInterceptor extends Interceptor {
  @override
  Future onResponse(Response response) async {
    response.data =await compute(decrypt,response.data); //freezes here
    return super.onResponse(response);
  }
}
  Object decrypt(Object object){
    return result;
  }
```

It has some restrictions though for the type of data you can pass in argument and retrieve as result. You can learn more [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/compute.html).

Answer (score 6):

Asynchronous programming paradigm is based on single threaded model. Async optimizes CPU usage by not waiting I/O tasks to complete. Instead, it puts a callback to the task and tells it "call this when you done". Now it can handle other work while the task completes and calls the callback. This makes sense when tasks are HTTP requests or file operations since these will handled by other devices not the CPU. But if the task is CPU intensive then using async will not help.

You can have a look at [Isolate](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-isolate/dart-isolate-library.html), equivalent of thread in Dart. You can create a seperate isolate and run your heavy tasks there.

There is also [`compute()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/compute-constant.html) method. It takes a function and argument, then evaluate that function with the supplied argument on a seperate isolate and returns the result as `Future`. This is much easier and gets the job done.

A dummy method that is CPU intensive:

```
int heavyTask(int n) {
  int z = n;
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    i % 2 == 0 ? z-- : z += 3;
  }
  return z + n;
}
```

Using `compute()` method to run it on a seperate isolate:

```
 compute(heavyTask, 455553000)
     .then((res) => print("result is $res"));
```